# Which package contains cygisccfg-163.dll

Tags: cygwin

I get:

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/host.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygisccfg-163.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried removing `bind-utils` and re-installing it. But no luck.

It seems there is a dependency that is not resolved correctly.

How do I find out which package contains cygisccfg-163.dll? An ideal answer would also show how I would find in general which package provides a certain fail (similar to `apt-file search`).

Answer (score 1):

Use Cygcheck to find the package

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/cygisccfg-163.dll
Found 6 matches for bin/cygisccfg-163.dll
bind-debuginfo-9.11.5-2.P4 - bind-debuginfo: Debug info for bind
bind-debuginfo-9.11.6-1 - bind-debuginfo: Debug info for bind
bind-debuginfo-9.11.9-1 - bind-debuginfo: Debug info for bind
libisccfg163-9.11.5-2.P4 - libisccfg163: BIND named.conf parser library
libisccfg163-9.11.6-1 - libisccfg163: BIND named.conf parser library
libisccfg163-9.11.9-1 - libisccfg163: BIND named.conf parser library
```